# Won't exit Do loop

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone tell me why this code never exits the Do loop?  I have managed to come up with a work around, but I'm puzzled as to why it doesn't work as is.  Same results running under Excel 2003 or 2010.

```
Public Declare Function EnableWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal fEnable As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function IsWindowEnabled Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean

Sub test()
    Dim b As Boolean, h As Long

    h = FindWindow("xlmain", Application.Caption)

    Do
        EnableWindow h, True
        b = IsWindowEnabled(h)
    Loop Until b = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your workaround involve throwing a DoEvents after EnableWindow h, True? My guess is that the loop is executing so fast, it doesn't update the UI. Excel doesn't give control to the UI Thread while looping unless you use DoEvents. It probably wouldn't hurt to throw an Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) in there as well.

Comment: @user1274820 Thanks for the suggestions, but that doesn't seem to resolve it.  If I step thru it manually, even though `b = True`, the loop continues.  It looks like IsWindowEnabled is somehow breaking the Do loop.  Oddly, I've discovered that this line does work `If IsWindowEnabled(h) Then Exit Do`

Comment: Interesting. From the official documentation, it says that it returns a non-zero number - sounds to me like maybe there's an issue with assigning something besides a 0 or a 1 to a boolean? It may also have to do with "true" simply equaling one and the value assigned being something different. "If the window is enabled, the return value is nonzero." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting article that I believe holds the key to your problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx

It basically says, that different coding languages represent bool in  different manners.

Behind the scenes, bool is actualy a numerical variable.

In vba the value of False is represented as **(-1)**.

You can test this if you do:

```
Public sub TestBool
   dim b as boolean
   b = 1
   msgbox cint(b)  '->> the result will be -1, not 1
End sub
```

As you can see above, in the "b = 1" line vba does a secret conversion from 1 to -1.
However, my bet is that, when you declare IsWindowEnabled as boolean, because
this is external code, vba does not do the "heavy lifting" for you, and does
not do the above conversion (I guess **IsWindowEnabled**  is **written in C**, **where their bool is represented as 1**).

So, in the line :

```
Loop Until b = True
```

what actually happens is this :

```
Loop until 1 = -1
```

You can test this by adding before the "loop until" the following line:

```
msgbox clng(b) & " " & clng(True)
```

There are a few solutions:

1. Declare IsWindowEnabled as Long  (I think this is the best solution):

   Public Declare Function IsWindowEnabled Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As **Long**
2. Declare b as variant (it works, as of now, not sure why) :

   Dim b

-EDIT (30.3.15)-
This is a small sub to demonstrate the matter :

Private Declare Function IsWindowEnabled Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean

```
Private Sub Demo_API_true_in_VBA()
    Dim b As Boolean
    Dim b2 As Boolean

    b = 1
    Debug.Print "b = 1 :  " & "Clng(b)=" & CLng(b) & "  b=" & b
    'result- b = 1 :  Clng(b)=-1  b=True

    b = -1
    Debug.Print "b = -1:  " & "Clng(b)=" & CLng(b) & "  b=" & b
    'result- b = -1:  Clng(b)=-1  b=True

    Debug.Print

    b2 = IsWindowEnabled(Application.hWnd)
    Debug.Print "b2 = IsWindowEnabled() :  " & "Clng(b2)=" & CLng(b2) & "  b2=" & b2
    'result- b2 = IsWindowEnabled() :  Clng(b2)=1  b2=True
    ' NOTE HERE THAT b2 equels to 1, not to  -1 !!!

    Debug.Print

    Debug.Print "b = " & b & " ; " & "b2 = " & b2  ' both will **appear** as True
    'result- b = True ; b2 = True

    Debug.Print

    ' However, the result of the comparison here will be False !!!
    ' because vba actually does a numerical comparison, and 1 <> -1 .
    Debug.Print "Is b = b2 ?  " & CStr(b = b2)   
    'result- Is b = b2 ?  False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's an interesting observation - declaring b as a variant does indeed make it work.  However, this does not make any sense to me.  In my original code, `b` does change from `False` to `True`, so the loop should exit regardless.  As for the different representations of True, I am aware of that.  Try this (with b declared as boolean) - `b=1:Debug.Print b` and `b=-1:Debug.Print b`.  In both cases, b=True.   I still maintain one of the API's is breaking the loop.

Comment: The API is breaking the loop, but by a different manner- there seem to be a logical bug when you declare a API sub as boolean in VBA, and the return result is "TRUE", which in fact equals to 1 (where as VBA's True is -1)     --->> I have taken the code you wrote in the comment, and added a demo sub to my answer, so as to make the process more clean.

Comment: Sorry, I'm away from home and have no access to Excel to test this.  Will check it out as soon as I'm back, after the weekend.

Comment: I ran your code verbatim, but with different results than you show.  I've edited your code above to show my results, and as you can see, they're a bit different than yours.  Run in both xl2003 and xl2010.  I'm going to close this post (I don't feel there's any point in continuing) and I will check off the answered box, although I do have a few reservations.  I appreciate your interest.

Comment: I see the comments I added to your code have been removed, apparently they didn't make sense to some people!  Anyway, I was getting different slightly different results than you were, and now I see why: - your API: `Private Declare Function IsWindowEnabled Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean`.  And here's the version I'm using that I got from API Viewer: `Declare Function IsWindowEnabled Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long`.  As you can see, slightly different declarations, causing slightly different results.

Comment: Hi, in your original code above it seems that you wrote the API as "Private Declare Function IsWindowEnabled Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As ***Boolean****", not as Long.   Using Long as the return value should solve the issue, as I also wrote above. Anyway, glad I could help and thanks for marking the post as answered.

Comment: Yes, I see now that I made a typo - it was a very long day!  Thanks.